# bank doesn't issue 1099 for open bonus of checking account

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have stayed in US as a F1 student for more than 5 years, so have filed tax as a resident alien since more than two years ago.

1. Last year, I opened a checking account with a bank, and received opening bonus of 200 dollars.
2. This year I haven't received any tax form about the bonus from the bank. So I asked a bank representative recently, and he said their system couldn't generate a tax form for me, and was not sure why but some possible reasons were:

   - they looked up my record, and found that when I opened the account last year, a bank staff member gave me a single-page W8BEN form to fill out and sign, which at that time I didn't know was an incorrect form for a resident alien.
   - they recently closed my account upon my request, because I didn't want to go through the hassle in order to waive the monthly maintenance fee.

My questions are:

1. For a nonresident alien for tax purpose,

   Although I am a resident alien now, I forgot what it was when I was
   a nonresident alien during my first five years in US, and required
   to fill out W8BEN.  I vaguely remember that a nonresident alien
   might pay at a higher tax rate than a resident alien, but the bank
   says it didn't generate 1099 for me (so didn't report to IRS my bonus) possibly because I filled out
   W8BEN when opening the account.

   so how does filling out and signing a single-page W8BEN form affect
   the tax  on a nonresidenent alien? Does it increase or decrease the
   tax rate for a nonresident alien?
2. In my case, and me as a resident alien for tax purpose

   Although the representative at the bank said that their system
   couldn't correct the mistake of me filling out W8BEN, are there
   possible solutions to correct it?

   Or like what he said, the bank has never reported 1099 to IRS, and I
   might  just not report the bonus? Is there any risk if not reporting
   it?

Thanks.

Comment: If the bank have not sent a 1099 then the risk of the IRS finding out by themselves is very slim. They would however *expect* you to report it, and might get grumpy if they later found out by means of an audit, etc (though that's also unlikely to happen). As a student though, I would assume your marginal rate is pretty low. What's the tax liability on this - $20-30? Maybe better to report it and pay tax just for piece of mind. Don't know about W8BEN.

Comment: This is not considered income, there is no reason to report it.

Comment: @PeteB are you sure about that? I typically receive a 1099-INT in the years I have received an account opening bonus from a bank.

Comment: @PeteB. Unfortunately they are considered similar to interest and thus taxable (see [this article](http://creditcardforum.com/blog/do-you-have-to-pay-taxes-on-bank-account-bonuses/) for example).

Comment: What is your taxable income for the year? It's possible you are under the minimum to even file a return.

Comment: @PeteB. - cash back based on credit card usage, for example, is not taxable, but these bonuses aren't a return of ones own money, so even without the 1099, taxable.

Comment: @joe Thanks.yes, it is this year, and I have to file return because I have wages. do you know which line in 1040 I should report my bank bonus 200 dollars?

Comment: If you choose to claim the $200 as income, line 21 "other income" is a safe line to use.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. (1) I have an exempt of X dollars from a treaty between US and another country for F1 student, and line 21 is where I used to put minus amount of the exempt, i.e. -X, and write "US-xxx treaty article xxx" in the box left to line 21 . This time shall I put their sum -X+200 in line 21? Shall I worry that the sum hides the two different items? (2) Shall I write a letter explaining about 200 bonus without 1099 generated because of filling the wrong W8BEN for me as a resident alien for tax? Or is there no need to do so?